# How to get current time or date directly from internet?

Tags: php, html, datetime, time

My computer have lost the power of `CMOS` battery! And my computer is showing current year as `2004` and time as `12:00 AM`! And one of my codes are not working well like --

```
<?php
  echo date("Y");
?>
```

Which provides me the output as ---

```
2004
```

But I know that the current year is 2011. Also in Facebook and Stack overflow and other sites the time is correct! How is this possible? Is there any other code for displaying the current `date` and `time`? Can anyone suggest me a code that could provide my website users correct timing even when there `CMOS` has failed or is out of battery.

Comment: are you hosting your site on your pc? get a server from any of the providers and they will surely provide you with the correct time. also, are you enjoying your stay in the year 2011? where's your delorean parked?

Comment: Thanks but can you suggest me a script, please.

Comment: You're asking how Facebook and Stack Overflow show the correct time and date? It's because they use the server time/date. When you execute your PHP script locally, your machine is the server, and it's picking up your machines time and date. If/once you upload your script to your web host (assuming your not hosting this locally) your script will use the servers date/time and this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running Linux (or some variant)? I found this page in a quick google search.

[NTP Time Synchronization Script](http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/php/ntp_time_synchronization/index.php)

The problem like Stofke said is that PHP just grabs the time from your computer because it doesn't know about NTP or stuff like that.  So what you really need is a script that makes sure your server has accurate time and then PHP will grab the accurate time from your server.

**EDIT**: Also just as a resource, this link explains how to sync up to ntp via the command line and has a little excerpt about Windows at the bottom too.
[NTP HOWTO](http://www.brennan.id.au/09-Network_Time_Protocol.html)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is run on the server so it takes the server time.

Right now I assume you develop on your local computer so it acts as the server and displays it wrong but once you upload your scripts to an online server it will use the time/date of that server and if that one is set correctly your users will see 2011.

Answer (score 0):

All you need: http://www.whattimeisit.com/

Comment: This link was great. Thanks it helped a lot!